# h:commandbutton doesn't work in h:datatable

Tags: jsf

Hi guys `<h:commandbutton>` with `<f:ajax>` doesn't work in `<h:datatable>`.
It works when it is out of `<h:panelgroup>` and `<h:datatable>`. But in this case, it doesn't work.

```
<h:panelGroup  id="output4">
    <h:dataTable border="1" class="data_table" value="#{admin.list}" var="o">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Id</f:facet>
                #{o.id}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet  name="header">İsim</f:facet>
                #{o.isim}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Yazar/Yönetmen/Yapımcı/Sanatçı</f:facet>
                #{o.yazar}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Yayınevi</f:facet>
                #{o.yayinevi}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Fiyat</f:facet>
            #{o.fiyat} &#8378;
        </h:column>
        <h:column >
            <f:facet  name="header">İşlem</f:facet>
            <h:panelGroup id="userPanel">
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:form>
                        <h:commandButton value="Sil" >
                            <f:param name="islem" value="2" />
                            <f:param name="id" value="#{o.id}" />
                            <f:ajax execute="@this" event="action" id="5" 
                                    listener="#{test.deleteRecord()}" />
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </h:form>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Do you have a `<h:form>` that wraps your `<h:dataTable>`?

Comment: Any warning in console when click button? Also no need to define `event="action"` Remove the `id=5` also. It comes repetitive.

Comment: That's your problem them. Remove the inner `<h:form>` that you added inside `<h:column>`. Basic HTML doesn't allow having nested forms.

Comment: possible duplicate of [h:commandLink / h:commandButton is not being invoked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)